# My edited files not appear in TFS's Pending Changes window

Tags: version-control, tfs

I am using VS2010's TFS and have this problem: after 'Get latest version', and try to edit the file, it does not appear in Pending Changes window. I have to use the option 'Check out to Edit' for every files I want to change. It makes me missing some files when working with a big project. Any one have idea to fix this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Go to `File -> Source Control -> Go Online` and it will fix this problem.

Comment: only for lower VS

Comment: Works in VS2022

Answer (score 14):

I didn't see `File -> Source Control -> Go Online` option. I fixed it by clicking on item and selecting option to `check out for edit`. That worked.

Comment: I had X pending changes, tried checking out just the .sln file, and that didn't add anything to my Pending Changes window except the .sln file (not good enough).  Then I did a "check out for edit" on the folder that contained the .sln file, and that added everything under it to my Pending Changes window (this was the fix I needed).

Comment: @John
This was not the solution for me , I just wanted the changed files to be reflected in my Pending Changes . now everything even the files that are unchanged and already checked-in are also there in Pending Changes. How to fix this !

Comment: The file in question appeared as checked-out in the Source Control Explorer. I had to undo changes to the file and then check it out again for it to work. I'm glad I even noticed that it was missing from the pending changes...

Answer (score 6):

Did you already opened the project that you are working on through the `Source control window`? If you do that and your solution is not yet bound to TFS it will be asked now. So `bind` your solution and projects and then your changes will be visible and you do not need to do check out to edit. You can also see if this is already done by checking if there are `vssscc files` next to your solution files.

Comment: The way I worked is **Connect to Team Foundation Server** and open project from the source control, it is already mapped to my workspace and the file **vssscc** exist. But it still not work

Comment: Then checkout this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/88d652fa-1fef-4e3c-8dcb-a2079a96f031/ Here are some steps or things you can check to make it work like it needs to be.

Comment: From the link above: go to *Tools/Options/Enviroment/Documents* and make sure *Allow editing of read-only files* is **not** checked. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue after a connection problem - this caused VS/TFS to think I had nothing checked out. The solution was just to refresh the status via File, Source Control, Advanced, Refresh Status.

Answer (score 3):

Restart Visual Studio and all could be well!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Solution Explorer > Right click on solution > Click "Go Online"

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the specified file, then select check-in. whit this action file goes to the pending changes

Answer (score 1):

For me, in the context menu of the solution I had an option to 'Add this solution to source control...'.
If you also have this option you should go and add it again. You can keep same location and Ignore All warnings.

For me only after doing this it started seeing the file changes again.

My solution was also online and apparently nothing else was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Our **TFS** had errors so after I got it back it only saw new `userControls` added not edited ones, this is how I fixed it:

> RightClick -> Add Files To Source Control -> Keep Local Version (or server)

It had lost it's connection to the folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2022. Go to the `File > Source Control > Go online` was solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in VS2012, none of the answers above worked.

Fixed by opening "Go to All Changes" and including all missing files from there.

If I exclude any of these again, they do not appear under "Excluded changes", and have to be manually included from "Go to All Changes".

Comment: where do I find "Go to All Changes"?

Comment: @Andre https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU6Zv.gif (stolen from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282954/tfs-show-really-all-changes))

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2017, if you have the red checkmarks next to your files,

1. open `Team Explorer` box/window -> `Pending Changes`,
2. select your files in `Included Changes`, provide comment
3. click on `Check In` button

Answer (score 0):

In excluded changes, click on 'detected' and you will get a dialog box with all detected changes but not added to source control. Choose the changes u want to check in and then click on promote. You will be able to see the changes in the included section and you can check in.

Answer (score 0):

For me was only solution making new workspace with shorter path without special chars. So I didnt use folders like users and stuff but ProgramFiles. Maybe it was because of Win 7.

And run VS as admin for making directories in ProgramFiles

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 Check that all projects are bound there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manage Workspaces -> Edit (the workspace you are using)-> Advanced ->  Change Location item from "Server" to "**Local**".  This solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the mapping in source control.
Open Team explorer -> Source Control Explorer
Check the Local Path mapping.. if it is not appropriate, map it again with correct path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the two files ".cs" that were missing in the "*Included Changes*" section, I have to follow these steps:

- In the "Team Explorer" window - under the "***Excluded Changes***" section -, select the "***Show All***" dropdown and select the option "***Custom filter***".
- In the text field that appears after the selection was made, type the name of the file - *it's not needed to type the full name*.
- The file results will show and then, you can right-click over the files found and select "***Include***".
- The included file(s) should now be shown in the "*Included Changes*" section.

Answer (score 0):

VS2019Pro, Source Control Explorer -> Branch -> Right click -> Get Latest Version -> Conflict resolution did the trick for me