# TFS: Show really all changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

From time to time, when I want to check in with Visual Studio (2012) my pending changes to Team Explorer, I get a strange abstract "Included Changes **(x of y)**" Where **x** is smaller than **y**. Even when I check in from the root directory of the solution and when I select "Show all" I can't see really all changes.

In the case below: When I set "Show Solution Changes" I see 96 of 452, when I select "Show all" I see 178 of 452. The missing files are part of the solution and common source files as the others.

[image: Tfs_Show_All]

P.S: Policy warning is irrelevant and conflicts are irrelevant to this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Show All` simply removes any filter you have applied using either `Show Solution Changes` or `Custom Filter`.

If you want to view all your changes, you need to use the `Go to All Changes` link, right next to your `Show All` Link. This will show you the complete list of all changes across the workspace.

It takes a little getting used to, but I actually quite like it this way. I believe the rationale behind doing it was to keep that space fairly small, so as not to push the Excluded Items list way to the bottom (Excluded Items will also behave in the same manner, I believe).

There is an extension for Visual Studio called [Team Pilgrim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222) that will give you a version of the old style pending changes window.

Another point of note is that this behaviour is no longer the case in VS2013 ([1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761735/team-explorer-pending-changes-list-doesnt-show-all-the-files-with-pending-changes)) (Thanks to StefanG for pointing this out)

Comment: I don't like this behavior, because: in most cases all files are shown, so I just overfly the list and exclude some folders that should stay local. In some cases, not all files are shown and I forget them (happens everytime - I am a creature of habit and I forget it because its not logical).

And even when I use "Go to all changes", I can't see the structure because it's a flat list. Is there no better way, to really show all?

Comment: Not built in. There is an extension you could use but I personally recommend giving it a chance, you'll be surprised how quickly you adapt. Let me see if I can find it and I'll update the answer

Comment: I give the plugin a try. Btw: I googled "Go to all changes" and I found http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761735/team-explorer-pending-changes-list-doesnt-show-all-the-files-with-pending-changes . Microsoft regards it as a bug and fixes it with VS 2013.

Comment: You know, I'm *using* 2013, and I just hadn't noticed that change. I'm rarely checking in more than about 30 files at a time though, so I probably just assumed that it was still doing it.

I'll mention that in the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but I recently encountered it while searching for a similar problem and for me I was seeing files that were previously checked in show up under All Changes for a solution that didn't show up when viewing Solution Changes.

For me the only thing that fixed it was closing VS and renaming the hidden $tfs directories in my TFS folder. Upon opening VS again new $tfs directories were created and all of my issues went away.